# Why is it mandatory to initialise static final variables?

Tags: java, initialization, final

Consider a `static` variable, for example:

```java
private static int x;
```

If we try printing its value in the main method, it will be 0. So the variable is initialised. Now consider if the variable is `final`:

```java
private static final int x;
```

This is not possible; why? We have to initialise it like `private static final int x = 2;`, or using a static initialiser like:

```java
static {
    x = 2;
}
```

A `static` variable is initialised by default; so why is there a compilation error if the variable is also `final`?

Comment: It's not possible to modify a `final` field after declaration, using a default for something that can't be changed later is probably not desired behavior (since the default is `0` or `null` for almost all cases).

Answer (score 8):

In principle the language could let you declare a `static final` field and have it take its default value, but in practice if you fail to give an explicit value for a `static final` field then it is almost always by mistake. So the compiler gives you an error here because

1. This code does something you almost certainly didn't want it to do (or, fails to do something you almost certainly *did* want to do), and
2. The default value will be something trivial like 0 or `null`, so if using that value *is* what you intended, then the inconvenience imposed on you is minimal; you just have to write `static final int x = 0;` instead of `static final int x;`.

In fact, being forced to write `= 0` or `= null` explicitly makes your code easier to read, understand and maintain. Keep in mind that most code will be read hundreds or thousands of times more often than it is written, so you are actually saving time by being more verbose and explicit.

Comment: so is it made only for readablility purpose?. when we are making  a member static it is allocated in the static part of memory corresponding to the process of the program.and static part is initialised by default. so there is no difference between unintialised and initialised. then how the final declaration finds out it is initialised or not  ?

Comment: @anoob Read the answer again.  Java *could* initialize it, but that almost certainly is not what the developer intended, and in nearly every case, it would not be useful.

Comment: It is not only for readability purposes; it is for at least two reasons, the main one being to inform the programmer when they have done something which is almost certainly a mistake. There is a difference between "definitely assigned" and "not definitely assigned", which is what the compiler is checking for when a variable is `final`. See the JLS's chapter on [definite assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html).

Comment: @VGR Technically it's slightly more complicated than that, because Java often *does* initialise the `final` field with a default value before its actual value is assigned. (This occurs if the `final` field's initialiser is not a "constant expression" as defined in the JLS.) The thing the compiler is checking for is not that the field is "initialised" but that the field is "definitely assigned", although that's a subtle distinction which shouldn't matter in real code written sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph from [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):
The final modifier indicates that the value of this field cannot change.

For example, the following variable declaration defines a constant named PI, whose value is an approximation of pi (the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter):

```
static final double PI = 3.141592653589793;
```

Constants defined in this way cannot be reassigned, and it is a compile-time error if your program tries to do so. By convention, the names of constant values are spelled in uppercase letters. If the name is composed of more than one word, the words are separated by an underscore (_).

Edit:
Please, check the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4). The answer to your question is there.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** The **static** keyword on your question title can be removed because you should initialize **all** final variables and not only static final ones.

All final variables should be **explicitly** initialized or at the point of declaration or in every constructor of the class in which it is declared ( in this case it is named **blank final** variable ). This because a final variable value can't be changed after first assignment. So language raises warning to **implicitly** assignments to final variables to drive developer to explicitly assign a value ( even if it is the default one like '0' for Integers ).

Moreover in the specific case of a "static final" variable you can also assign the value in a static initializer of the class in which it is declared.